# What is the correct way to create a feature extractor for a hugging face (HF) ViT model?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

TLDR: is the correct way to extract features from a HF ViT model `outputs.pooler_output` or `outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0]`? where outputs is `outputs: BaseModelOutputWithPooling = self.model(pixel_values=batch_xs)`.

---

Given only the ViT model it's not clear what one should do to solve a vision
classification problem. I eventually converged to this answer (but I am unsure if it is correct or the best anymore, will provide full code at the end):

```
        outputs: BaseModelOutputWithPooling = self.model(pixel_values=batch_xs)
        output: Tensor = self.dropout(outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0])
        logits: Tensor = self.cls(output)
```

Intuitively it makes sense, we can to extract the features from the cls token position. However, once I printed all the layers for the ViTModel I would have personally chosen a different layer because it's right before the cls layer AND because printing the activations seem to be in a better range to be honest. I would have chosen the ones in the `(pooler): ViTPooler(...)` layer, right after the `Tanh()`. Doing that results in this:

```
outputs: BaseModelOutputWithPooling = self.model(pixel_values=batch_xs)

outputs.pooler_output
tensor([[-0.3976, -0.8454, -0.0601,  ..., -0.2804, -0.1822,  0.1917],
        [-0.3392, -0.0248,  0.1346,  ..., -0.5822,  0.8779,  0.4147],
        [-0.2980, -0.8038, -0.1146,  ...,  0.2431, -0.0963,  0.7844],
        ...,
        [-0.1237, -0.7514,  0.7388,  ..., -0.8551,  0.1512,  0.6157],
        [ 0.5351, -0.9040,  0.0387,  ..., -0.0773,  0.2704, -0.0311],
        [ 0.2142, -0.3138,  0.0426,  ..., -0.5943,  0.2873,  0.4420]],
       grad_fn=<TanhBackward>)
outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0]
tensor([[ 5.7313e-01, -2.1335e+00,  2.0491e-01,  ..., -1.2373e-01,
         -2.0056e-01, -4.8167e-01],
        [ 5.3309e-02, -1.6563e+00,  1.5719e+00,  ..., -1.3617e+00,
         -3.0064e-01, -2.0056e-01],
        [-2.0633e-02, -2.1370e+00,  9.9927e-01,  ..., -2.3584e+00,
          8.6123e-01, -1.2759e+00],
        ...,
        [ 3.9583e-01, -1.3500e+00,  1.7638e+00,  ..., -9.9536e-01,
          1.0843e+00, -4.4368e-01],
        [ 1.6026e+00, -6.4654e-01,  2.4882e+00,  ..., -1.0347e+00,
         -1.3160e-03, -2.4357e+00],
        [-1.2769e-02, -9.6574e-01,  1.6432e+00,  ..., -7.9090e-01,
          6.1669e-01,  3.2990e-01]], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
```

and sums for sanity checks

```
outputs.pooler_output.sum()
tensor(3.8430, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0].sum()
tensor(-6.4373e-06, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
```

and shapes

```
outputs.pooler_output.shape
torch.Size([25, 768])
outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0].shape
torch.Size([25, 768])
```

which for `outputs.pooler_output.shape` look much better behaves. But my forward pass uses `outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0]` for some reason.

Which one should I have used?

Full code:

```
class ViTForImageClassificationUU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 num_classes: int,
                 image_size: int,  # 224 inet, 32 cifar, 84 mi, 28 mnist, omni...
                 criterion: Optional[Union[None, Callable]] = None,
                 # Note: USL agent does criterion not model usually for me e.g nn.Criterion()
                 cls_p_dropout: float = 0.0,
                 pretrained_name: str = None,
                 vitconfig: ViTConfig = None,
                 ):
        """
        :param num_classes:
        :param pretrained_name: 'google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k'  # what the diff with this one: "google/vit-base-patch16-224"
        """
        super().__init__()
        if vitconfig is not None:
            raise NotImplementedError
            self.vitconfig = vitconfig
            print(f'You gave a config so everyone other param given is going to be ignored.')
        elif pretrained_name is not None:
            raise NotImplementedError
            # self.vit = ViTModel.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k')
            self.model = ViTModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_name)
            print('Make sure you did not give a vitconfig or this pretrained name will be ignored.')
        else:
            self.num_classes = num_classes
            self.image_size = image_size
            self.vitconfig = ViTConfig(image_size=self.image_size)
            self.model = ViTModel(self.vitconfig)
        assert cls_p_dropout == 0.0, 'Error, for now only p dropout for cls is zero until we figure out if we need to ' \
                                     'change all the other p dropout layers too.'
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(cls_p_dropout)
        self.cls = nn.Linear(self.model.config.hidden_size, num_classes)
        self.criterion = None if criterion is None else criterion

    def forward(self, batch_xs: Tensor, labels: Tensor = None) -> Tensor:
        """
        Forward pass of vit. I added the "missing" cls (and dropout layer before it) to act on the first cls
        token embedding. Remaining token embeddings are ignored/not used.

        I think the feature extractor only normalizes the data for you, doesn't seem to even make it into a seq, see:
        ...
        so idk why it's needed but an example using it can be found here:
            - colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z1lbR_oTSaeodv9tTm11uEhOjhkUx1L4?usp=sharing#scrollTo=cGDrb1Q4ToLN
            - blog with trainer https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-vit
            - single PIL notebook https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/VisionTransformer/Quick_demo_of_HuggingFace_version_of_Vision_Transformer_inference.ipynb
        """
        outputs: BaseModelOutputWithPooling = self.model(pixel_values=batch_xs)
        output: Tensor = self.dropout(outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0])
        logits: Tensor = self.cls(output)
        if labels is None:
            assert logits.dtype == torch.float32
            return logits  # this is what my usl agent does ;)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError
            assert labels.dtype == torch.long
            #   loss = self.criterion(logits.view(-1, self.num_classes), labels.view(-1))
            loss = self.criterion(logits, labels)
            return loss, logits

    def get_embedding(self, batch_xs: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        """
        Get the feature embedding of the first cls token.

        Details:
        By observing the ViTLayer, the (pooler) ViTPoooler(...) has an activation and a Tanh() layer.
        From playing around
        <TanhBackward>, so it seems that it the right one. Plus, printing
            outputs.pooler_output.sum()
            tensor(3.8430, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
        looks more sensible than trying to get the features for the cls position manually:
            outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0, :].sum()
            tensor(-6.4373e-06, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
        which looked weird.
        """
        # outputs: BaseModelOutputWithPooling = self.model(pixel_values=batch_xs)
        outputs: BaseModelOutputWithPooling = self.model(pixel_values=batch_xs)
        feat = outputs.pooler_output
        # out = model.model(x)
        # hidden_states = out.last_hidden_state
        # # Get the CLS token's features (position 0)
        # cls_features = hidden_states[:, 0]
        # return out
        # Obtain the outputs from the base ViT model
        # outputs = self.model(pixel_values, *args, **kwargs)
        # pooled_output = outputs.pooler_output
        # image_representation = outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0, :]
        return feat

    def _assert_its_random_model(self):
        from uutils.torch_uu import norm
        pre_trained_model = ViTModel.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k')
        print(f'----> {norm(pre_trained_model)=}')
        print(f'----> {norm(self)=}')
        assert norm(pre_trained_model) > norm(self), f'Random models usually have smaller weight size but got ' \
                                                     f'{norm(pre_trained_model)}{norm(self)}'


def get_vit_get_vit_model_and_model_hps(vitconfig: ViTConfig = None,
                                        num_classes: int = 5,
                                        image_size: int = 84,  # 224 inet, 32 cifar, 84 mi, 28 mnist, omni...
                                        criterion: Optional[Union[None, Callable]] = None,  # for me agent does it
                                        cls_p_dropout: float = 0.0,
                                        pretrained_name: str = None,
                                        ) -> tuple[nn.Module, dict]:
    """get vit for mi, only num_classes = 5 and image size 84 is needed. """
    model_hps: dict = dict(vitconfig=vitconfig,
                           num_classes=num_classes,
                           image_size=image_size,
                           criterion=criterion,
                           cls_p_dropout=cls_p_dropout,
                           pretrained_name=pretrained_name)
    model: nn.Module = ViTForImageClassificationUU(**model_hps)
    print('Its recommended to set args.allow_unused = True for ViT models.')
    return model, model_hps

def vit_forward_pass():
    # - for determinism
    import random
    import numpy as np
    random.seed(0)
    torch.manual_seed(0)
    np.random.seed(0)

    # - options for number of tasks/meta-batch size
    device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    # - get my vit model
    vitconfig: ViTConfig = ViTConfig()
    # model = ViTForImageClassificationUU(num_classes=64 + 1100, image_size=84)
    model = get_vit_get_vit_model_and_model_hps(vitconfig, num_classes=64 + 1100, image_size=84)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    # to device
    model.to(device)
    criterion.to(device)

    # - forward pass
    x = torch.rand(5, 3, 84, 84)
    y = torch.randint(0, 64 + 1100, (5,))
    logits = model(x)
    loss = criterion(logits, y)
    print(f'{loss=}')
```

cross: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-feature-extractor-for-a-hugging-face-hf-vit-model/34441

Answer (score 3):

> TLDR: is the correct way to extract features from a HF ViT model `outputs.pooler_output` or `outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0]`? where outputs is `outputs: BaseModelOutputWithPooling = self.model(pixel_values=batch_xs)`.

As per my understanding, I would go with the second option `outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0]`. Indeed, as per my interpretation and knowledge, using models as *feature extractors* means to freeze their bodies' weights, *remove any heads they could have* and retrieve the hidden states of the final layer. Then, especially for classification tasks, it is very common to just use the hidden state associated with the [CLS] token (such *token* nomenclature is also common to `ViT` and not only to NLP models, see the [original implementation](https://github.com/google-research/vision_transformer/blob/dc8ddbcdeefd281d6cc7fea0c97355495688ca9c/vit_jax/models.py#L280)).

The `ViT` paper states the following:

> [...] z_0^0 = x_class = x_0^{[CLS] token}, whose state at the output of the Transformer Encoder (z_L^0) serves as the image representation y. Both during pre-training and fine-tuning, a classification head is attached to z_L^0. ***The classification head is implemented by a MLP with one hidden layer at pre-training time and by a single linear layer at fine-tuning time***.

Therefore, imo, the pooled output that you get from the HF [`ViTPooler`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/68287689f2f0d8b7063c400230b3766987abf18d/src/transformers/models/vit/modeling_vit.py#L600) is part of the 2-layer (1 hidden layer, 1 output layer) classification head which is used at pre-training time on the *image classification task* the authors considered in the paper. (The other *self-supervised* task mentioned in the paper, *masked patch prediction*, does not consider such pre-training setting as it can be seen in [`ViTForMaskedImageModeling`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/68287689f2f0d8b7063c400230b3766987abf18d/src/transformers/models/vit/modeling_vit.py#L627)). Said differently, for me `ViTModel` instances with `add_pooling_layer=True` (which effectively rely on `ViTPooler`) serve the only purpose of reproducing the pre-training setting and indeed are not used anywhere.

If, besides the HF implementation, we were also to consider the implementations in the [original Google repo](https://github.com/google-research/vision_transformer/blob/main/vit_jax/models_vit.py), [here](https://github.com/google-research/vision_transformer/blob/85c4f53febd929c43e70e8ff598f9f00d52948b7/vit_jax/models_vit.py#L282)

```
[...]
x = self.encoder(name='Transformer', **self.transformer)(x, train=train)

if self.classifier == 'token':
    x = x[:, 0]
[...]

if self.representation_size is not None:
    x = nn.Dense(features=self.representation_size, name='pre_logits')(x)
    x = nn.tanh(x)
else:
    x = IdentityLayer(name='pre_logits')(x)

if self.num_classes:
    x = nn.Dense(
        features=self.num_classes,
        name='head',
        kernel_init=nn.initializers.zeros,
        bias_init=nn.initializers.constant(self.head_bias_init))(x)
return x
```

and in [torchvision](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/vision_transformer.py), [__init__](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/vision_transformer.py#L235)

```
heads_layers: OrderedDict[str, nn.Module] = OrderedDict()
if representation_size is None:
    heads_layers["head"] = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, num_classes)
else:
    heads_layers["pre_logits"] = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, representation_size)
    heads_layers["act"] = nn.Tanh()
    heads_layers["head"] = nn.Linear(representation_size, num_classes)

self.heads = nn.Sequential(heads_layers)
```

and [forward method](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/2b25d67925df9741ba2a75a07bc3046302969e87/torchvision/models/vision_transformer.py#L289)

```
def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor):
    [...]
    x = self.encoder(x)

    # Classifier "token" as used by standard language architectures
    x = x[:, 0]

    x = self.heads(x)

    return x
```

we would see that this idea seems to be valid.

Eventually, imo, this is further enforced by the fact that if you just run

```
from transformers import AutoModel
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224')
```

- `model` is a `ViTModel` instance (therefore it embeds the pooling layer by  default)
- you'll get a warning stating that

  > Some weights of the model checkpoint at google/vit-base-patch16-224 were not used when initializing ViTModel: ['***classifier.weight***', '***classifier.bias***']

  which is in line with the fact that we're not using any of the `ViT` models to be used in downstream tasks which have with a *final* (single linear layer) classification head on top of the encoder output (eg `ViTForImageClassification`)

*but especially*

- you'll get a warning stating that

  > Some weights of ViTModel were not initialized from the model checkpoint at google/vit-base-patch16-224 and are newly initialized: ['***vit.pooler.dense.weight***', '***vit.pooler.dense.bias***']

which I would interpret as an evidence of the fact that the pooler hidden states (i.e. the `pooler_output` that you're considering) are not part of the pre-trained checkpoint.

I've found the following very useful on this topic (but not with reference to `ViT` necessarily):

- https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/43
- https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/7540#issuecomment-704155218
- https://github.com/google-research/vision_transformer/issues/124

All this said, the difference is subtle in my opinion. It would be nice if you could get an answer in the HF forum, too.

Comment: I'm confused, what is `mdl.pooler_output`?

Comment: Not sure I get your question; that's the output of the [`ViTPooler`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/68287689f2f0d8b7063c400230b3766987abf18d/src/transformers/models/vit/modeling_vit.py#L600), which is a classification head put on top of the [CLS] token's final hidden state.